# what c++ syntax right for implementation of function of nested class with pass enum param as template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, enums, g++, clang

Ok. Here code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct A {    
    enum Status {
        one = 1
    };

    template< Status status >
    struct C;
};

template<typename T>
template<typename A<T>::Status status >
struct A<T>::C {
    void operator()() {
        cout << "C: " << (int)status << endl;
    };

//    void operator()();
};

// template<typename T>
// template<typename A<T>::Status status >
// void A<T>::C<status>::operator()() {
//    cout << "C: " << status << endl;
//}

int main()
{   
    A<int>::C<A<int>::one> c;
    c();

    return 0;
}
```

And it works with clang and g++ - compile and run.

But, if comment inline implementation A::C::operator()(), and uncomment commented declaration and out implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct A {    
    enum Status {
        one = 1
    };

    template< Status status >
    struct C;
};

template<typename T>
template<typename A<T>::Status status >
struct A<T>::C {
//    void operator()() {
//        cout << "C: " << (int)status << endl;
//    };

    void operator()();
};

template<typename T>
template<typename A<T>::Status status >
void A<T>::C<status>::operator()() {
    cout << "C: " << status << endl;
}

int main()
{   
    A<int>::C<A<int>::one> c;
    c();

    return 0;
}
```

clang doesn't make this:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp:28:23: error: nested name specifier 'A<T>::C<status>::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization
void A<T>::C<status>::operator()() {
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

but g++ really works:

```
$ g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
C: 1
```

I tried compile code with Visual C++ 2010 on work PC but both samples failed. I can't verify it now (no windows PC) and I'm not sure - maybe I made other mistakes...

Where mistake in second sample and what syntax right for out implementation?

Comment: I have no idea why this was voted for closure as unclear. Neither clang++ nor VC (no shock there) seem kosher with the same syntax as g++. This question simply wants to know if the definition clang and VC puke on while g++ consumes is because of clang et'al are broken or because g++ is too relaxed. If its the latter, is there a syntax that is *correct* ? (at least that was what I got from it).

Comment: VC2013 isn't happy with the generic implementations of `C::()()` but it seems to be happy with a specialisation. e.g. make your implementation specialised for `<int>` and it'll compile. I know this doesn't qualify as an answer but I hope it adds information to your investigation.

Comment: If `template<typename A<T>::Status status >` change by `template<int status >` everywhere both samples works fine with clang and g++. But I don't know how using enum.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are just forgot the template parameter in the implementation of struct C.
The following fixed code compiles file in Visual C++ 2010:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct A {    
    enum Status {
        one = 1
    };

    template< Status status >
    struct C;
};

template<typename T>
template<typename A<T>::Status status >
struct A<T>::C<status> {
    /*void operator()() {
        cout << "C: " << (int)status << endl;
    };*/

    void operator()();
};

template<typename T>
template<typename A<T>::Status status >
void A<T>::C<status>::operator()() {
    cout << "C: " << status << endl;
}

int main()
{   
    A<int>::C<A<int>::one> c;
    c();

    return 0;
}
```